# factory like pattern with spring bean without switch case

Tags: java, spring, switch-statement, case, factory

My goal is to return a method depending on a enum. Currently, I have created a factory but it's using a switch case that I dislike. The code is working fine but I want to use a better pattern and replace the current switch case. How would you design this without any switch case or if else (instance of)...

I tried also to implement a Stategy pattern in enum. But autowiring beans is not possible.

See below my current piece of code.

```
public enum Car {
     AUDI, FORD;
}
```

```
public class SuperCar{
     private Car car;
}
```

```
public class Audi extends SuperCar{
     // some other properties
}
```

```
public class Ford extends SuperCar{
     // some other properties
}
```

```
@Service
public class AudiService{

     public void save(Audi audi){
         // some code
     }

}
```

```
@Service
public class FordService{

     public void save(Ford ford){
         // some code
     }

}
```

```
@Service
public class CarFactory{

     private FordService fordService;
     private AudiService audiService;

     public CarFactory(FordService fordService, AudiService audiService) {
           this.fordService = fordService;
           this.audiService = AudiService;     
     }

     public void saveCar(SuperCar superCar){
         switch(superCar.getCar()):
             case AUDI:
                 return audiService.save((Audi)superCar));
             case FORD:
                 return fordService.save((Ford)superCar));
             default:
                 return null;

     }

}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is wrong with `switch`?  What do you mean by better? What criteria you use?

Comment: I prefer not to use switch because when an other developer add a new enum, he usually forgots to implement all switch pattern. I use them but it's best practice to avoid them

Comment: There is no pattern to solve this problem. I suggest you to create test which iterates thru `Car.values()` and call your factory method.

Comment: you could just throw an exception stating the newly added enum was not supported to know that there are missing lines of code in your factory

Comment: I've already done that. I was just trying to improve my code and get ride of all switch case. But I was expecting that answer. I've already searched everywhere on the internet.

Comment: I think this is only possible if you have a "service" associated with "object" ( in your case Car ) i.e. injected into the Enum itself. Did you try creating a constructor and lazy initialized or inject the service ?

Comment: Off topic: I think your class hierarchy is wrong, Ford clearly does not extend SuperCar

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I can't comment. Here the type of the car determines the car service. I'm not sure If the strategy patterns fits in here. I would use strategy pattern when there is a **varying service behavior** for the **same car**. Eg: In summer I want to use **XService** and in Winter I want to use **YService** for **AUDI**. I see two ways to implement this.

1. Inject the service during the creation of car object. With this implementation the car is tightly coupled with service. I don't recommend this, unless you have a strong reason to not follow point 2.
2. Use if/else or branching to determine the type of car and call the required service.

Answer (score 0):

In case of just replacing the `switch`, I would always prefer a more declarative approach by using a `map`, since it seams easier to maintain and to read:

```
private Map<Car, CarService> services;

public CarFactory(FordService fordService, AudiService audiService) {
   this.services = Map.of(Car.FORD, fordService, Car.AUDI, audiService);
}

public void saveCar(SuperCar superCar) {
   CarService service = services.get(superCar.getCar());
   if (service != null) service.save(..);
}
```

With the generic interface:

```
private interface CarService<T extends SuperCar> {
   void save(T car);
}
```

Anyway, I would rethink your object-model to let a super-car save itself (as others already suggested).